# what is Sqlite3, can we use it in coredata

Tags: ios, core-data, sqlite

i know about the core data in iOS and use the sqlite database in my project by creating XYZ.xcdatamodeld
but in other project i have seen the Sqlite3 and there is no database so i feel problem can any body tell me how can we use Sqlite3 in iOS ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From sqlite.org ...
SQLite is a software library that implements a self-contained, serverless, zero-configuration, transactional SQL database engine. SQLite is the most widely deployed SQL database engine in the world. The source code for SQLite is in the public domain.

Core Data is an Objective-C framework that is essentially an object graph that as one option can use SQLite as a persistent store.

You have many options when it comes to data persistence in iOS, but in my opinion and for simplicity, the two main options are coding direct to an SQLite database, or using Core Data. I recommend using Core Data.

When writing code for iOS, don't use add-ons, a waste of time in my opinion.

Learn to use Core Data properly and you will gain very powerful and useful skills in iOS.

Also read these books...

from The Pragmatic Bookshelf – "Core Data, 2nd Edition, Data Storage and Management for iOS, OS X, and iCloud" (Jan 2013) by Marcus S. Zarra.

from Apress publishers – "Pro iOS Persistence Using Core Data", by Michael Privat and Robert Warner (still in alpha).

Answer (score 1):

both are same and used for optimize the work  in iOS has `core Data` option , in android has not, `sqlite` also simple

use the following tutorial

1. http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_Example_SQLite_based_iOS_7_Application
2. http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ios/ios_sqlite_database.htm
3. http://www.appcoda.com/sqlite-database-ios-app-tutorial/

need insert , delete, update and select use this https://www.udemy.com/blog/ios-sqlite-tutorial/ and https://www.sqlite.org

Answer (score 1):

I think FMDB is the best choice for you ,it make the db operation more easily.

[FMDB git](https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb)